# Video Game Explanations in 10 Words or Less

Tags: logical-deduction, video-games

So, my friends and I came up with a new type of puzzle similar to that of the Every _____ Movie Reviewed in 10 Words or Less, in which movies are reviewed in 10 words or less. So my friends took this idea and used it in a puzzle format for 14 video games. See if you can decode them. Also, some of the games might have several names to them, so you might guess correctly, but in order to decode the secret message in the titles, the correct names are needed. So, here's the 14 puzzles.

1. Prehistoric Mario Bros. with blue and green hair.
2. Cute platypus destroys Fire Demon with water.
3. Don't use aimbot during a livestream on this game.
4. Genie that supposedly knows everything.
5. Screw traitorous jesters.
6. Prosecutor becomes defendant in the end game.
7. Civil War: NES Style.
8. Bosses include cyborgs, dragons, and cut out cardboard monsters!
9. Rolling barrels have become a common trope nowadays.
10. How can snails kill you? (Unsolved)
11. Medieval times had a lot of monsters.
12. Space Invaders Clone.
13. Teen shoots bad guys in hotels.
14. Boy shoots out rainbows to climb towers.

And that's all of them. So good luck, and see if you can decode the hidden message.

Hint:

> The secret message is both an arcade game and a recent Marvel series.

EDIT: I came up with Number 10 alone, but I feel now that the definition was too vague, so I have provided a new hint for it.

> The second word in Number 14 is the same as the last word in Number 11, minus one letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we go (answer is partial but includes starting points for the unanswered games based on the secret message):

Prehistoric Mario Bros. with blue and green hair.

> The game **Congo’s Caper** appears to feature a main character with blue hair, so I will go with that.

Cute platypus destroys Fire Demon with water.

> (answer by kayzeroshort) **Liquid Kids**

Don't use aimbot during a livestream on this game.

> **[Overwatch](https://www.google.com/amp/s/gamerant.com/overwatch-streamer-banned-live/amp/)**

Genie that supposedly knows everything.

> **Akinator** is a game similar to Twenty Questions in which a genie attempts to guess a character that you are thinking of.

Screw traitorous jesters.

> In one of the game modes of **Kirby Super Star**, the villainous Marx is a clown-like character that betrays Kirby and steals his wish in order for personal benefit.

Prosecutor becomes defendant in the end game.

> Maybe Phoenix Wright: **Ace Attorney**?

Civil War: NES Style.

> **[North and South](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_%26_South_(video_game))**

Bosses include cyborgs, dragons, and cut out cardboard monsters!

> **Donkey Kong 64** includes boss battles with a cyborg (a jack-in-the-box monster), a dragon (you p*** it off by squashing its baby), and a cardboard cutout (of King K. Rool).

Rolling barrels have become a common trope nowadays.

> **Donkey Kong** features rolling barrels that must be jumped by Jumpman.

How can snails kill you?

> (answer by LeppyR64) **Adventure Island**

Medieval times had a lot of monsters.

> (answer by EightAndAHalfTails) **Ghouls ‘n’ Ghosts** (or [its prequel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_%27n_Goblins_(video_game))?)

Space Invaders Clone.

> **Galaxian**, probably — given the swarm of aliens that scrolls side-to-side and advances toward the player.

Teen shoots bad guys in hotels.

> (answer by Philipp) **Elevator Action**

Boy shoots out rainbows to climb towers.

> (answer by practiced_liar) **Rainbow Islands: Towering Adventure**

We can find the secret message by:

> taking the first letter of each game to obtain: *Cloak and Dagger* (this is actually where I began)

Comment: The secret code is correct, so kudos to you for it. Your answers are correct, but I did have a few notes. One, Congo's Caper wasn't the game I was looking for, but it is a sequel to Caveman Ninja/Joe and Mac, which was the name I was looking for, but I'll accept it. Galaga was the name I was looking for instead of Galaxian but since it is a sequel to Galaxian, I'll accept both answers.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping a partial answer would be okay (for now), as I’ve noticed people tend to work together on small leftover parts of answers. Also happy that my answers are acceptable. :-)

Comment: I can only think of one more, but is the "Medieval times..." clue referring to either [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)(Tubhyf a Tubfgf) or its prequel?

Comment: `Boy shoots out rainbows to climb towers` sounds like (envaobj fvk fvrtr)

Comment: Number 11 is correct, but 14 is not.

Comment: I played a game on Atari that fits the description of 13, but I forgot its name. I'm guessing: could it be »ryringbe npgvba«?

Comment: I think #2 is [rot 13](https://www.rot13.com/)(Yvdhvq Xvqf).

Comment: Both 2 and 13 are correct, though my friend that came up with 2 was shocked someone got it.

Comment: I think 14 is rot13(Envaobj Vfynaqf: Gbjrevat Nqiragher)

Comment: According to the one who used this game for the puzzle, and I quote: "Any (Envaobj Vfynaqf) game will work for this one, it does not matter. But, even though (Envaobj Vfynaqf) is correct, anything from the original series not pertaining to (Envaobj Vfynaqf) is incorrect." It seemed strange he'd bring that up, but then again, he was the same one who made Puzzle 5 on one of my other questions. Good job.

Answer (score 3):

10. How can snails kill you?

    > Adventure Island

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Great job!